# I want to extract the text from a pdf which is in white background only using python

Tags: python, text, background-color

I need to extract the text from the portion which is in white background only. There are some other sections in the page having background color other than white. I don't want that text. Here is a sample image :

[image: sample]

I am attaching the PDF file format.

Comment: Hello Ajith, Please share more details which you have tried with related code if any

Comment: Welcome to SO Ajith! can you please include some code and some approach you tried, also the pdf that you are talking about please include the screenshot

Comment: Hello @AnkitAgrawal Please have a look on the screenshots. attached along with the link

Comment: hello @PatelRomil can you please help me

Comment: If for all cases, the text with non-white background is in the pink bordered box, then one approach would be to do contour detection and white-patching the whole box. Read text on the white-patched image afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  One of the ways which might be simpler would be to use pyPDF2.

$ pip install pyPDF2

It’s pretty stay forward to read file in python.

import PyPDF2

filename = "yourfile.pdf"

pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))

For further info documentation is at the site. 
(https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)